# Facebook graph API for comments not returning "replies" to comments

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have integrated the following tag in my JSP

```
<div 
    class="fb-comments" 
    data-href="http://localhost:81/GGO_JSP_Chat/ID1012.jsp" 
    data-num-posts="10" 
    data-width="470">
</div>
```

I have added a combination of comments and replies both on my website and FB page.

However, when I try retrieving the comments data using graph API, it just returns the 1st level comment. The subsequent replies/comments are not returned. The replies are viewable on FB and my site.

URL for retrieving graph API data:
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://localhost:81/GGO_JSP_Chat/ID1012.jsp

Comment: Further observations:                                                1.Further to the issue. If I add a reply using account "rohitxxxx", the replies show up in the graph API output. However, if I add replies using account "babsxxxx", the replies do not show up 
2. I added login with facebook button on my website. 

I am able to login with my username password for the "rohitxxxx" account. However for the "babsxxxx" account I get an "ERROR - An error occurred. Please try again later."

I have created the facebook app with "rohitxxxx" account. Is there a  app/user account setting I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. My application was in the sandbox mode. I disabled the sandbox mode and the replies started showing up.